# Can we say that every magnetic object has some magnetic potential for each and every magnet in this universe?

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, potential-energy

Suppose I have a permanent magnet. It would attract any iron piece(or some other magnetic substance) on taking it to any part of the world or the universe. So, every magnetic object must have some magnetic potential for my magnet. If it is true,  then can we trace this potential energy to the formation of the universe??

Answer (score 0):

> Every magnetic object must have some magnetic potential for my magnet
> That scientifically accurate but this type of force is so  rare and significant compared to the other forces like gravity, electrostatic forces that its effect will be negligible.

A good way to think about this, **did you ever feel or see Alpha Centauri's gravitational pull or even the Sun's pull. Did it affect the free fall of your ball**. No.

But yes since the Cosmic radiation background consists of electromagnetic waves, you can trace the origin of the universe somehow with your magnet. But no one knows how.